# Looking for good tutorials / documents for Postsharp laos, understanding of "Librarian" samples

Tags: c#, attributes, aop, postsharp

Can anyone point me to good learning material on PostSharp / laos plugin. I liked the "Librarian" sample shipped with Postsharp, it does cover lots of stuff, but is difficult to understand. Is there any explanation / writeup on samples too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a list of official and contributed documentation at http://www.postsharp.org/about/documentation.

Maybe the best advanced tutorial is the one of Ruurd Boeke at http://www.sitechno.com/Blog/IntroducingEntityFrameworkContribEasyIPocoImplementationV01.aspx.

Comment: Thanks. anyway PostSharp Rocks. Just need to understand all finer details. Also I liked your Librarian sample and its Architecture layers. Can I contact you for some presentation material which I need to train my office staff. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sure. Send me a message through the PostSharp forum.